# Chain touches frame after re-installing crank

Tags: chain, chainring, vintage, clearance

I'm restoring a vintage road bike. I had to strip the whole bike so I could get the paint off to re-spray so now I'm trying to put it all back together!

I was lining up the new-old front derailleur and noticed the inner ring is extremely close to the frame. I rested my new chain on the inner ring, gently rotated the crank arm and saw that the chain is actually going to hit the frame. If you look at the crank arm on the other side, you'll see it looks like it could go in more? Is it possible that the chain ring side is screwed too far and the other side isn't screwed enough? Any tips/suggestions?

Many thanks!

[image: Clearance]

Comment: I observe there is a recess dimple in the chainstay at that point, so its not quite as close as you might think by just sighting along the chainstay.  As they say "Clearance is clearance"  Is there a chance you misplaced a spacer between the drive side cup and the frame ?

Comment: Try flipping the spindle end for end. I think Nathan is right.

Comment: From the looks of it, I'd guess the spindle is flipped: the wide none drive-side gap between BB-housing and crank is revealing.

Answer (score 5):

Taper bores can sometimes become enlarged with repeated installations, which affects clearance some none-zero amount, but this looks too extreme to be caused by that. It looks like it's probably an asymmetrical spindle and it got installed with the long side on the left, which is incorrect. If it's not that then that's weird, but solvable with a longer spindle.